# Anaconda Prompt, where is the exe file saved on windows?

Tags: python, conda

I am looking for the exe file for `Anaconda Prompt`, I am looking `C:\Anaconda3\Scripts` and don't know what it's named?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your start menu, it should be there. Its a link named "Anaconda Prompt", that links to `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\...\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\...\Anaconda3`, it's executed in `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\SPB_16.6`

Comment: Are you able to make that into a windows shortcut?

Comment: Scripts folder does not exist on latest versions 2020.11